# SpringXD: How to make a job definition in seprate lines

Tags: spring-xd

I have a job definition that is very long. I wonder if there is a way to separate it into multiple lines for easy reading. I have tried with '\' or '\n' but they all failed on job creation, for example:

```
    xd:>job create --name myHttpJob --definition "httpJob \n
          job create --name myHttpJob --definition "httpJob \n
                                                ^
           Cannot have an unbalanced number of quotation marks
    xd:>--listeners=disable" --deploy
       Command '--listeners=disable" --deploy' not found (for assistance press TAB)

    xd:>job create --name myHttpJob --definition "httpJob \
         job create --name myHttpJob --definition "httpJob \
                                               ^
          Ran out of input in escape sequence
    xd:>--listeners=disable" --deploy
      Command '--listeners=disable" --deploy' not found (for assistance press TAB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this still helps someone out there.  I don't think you'll be able to separate the command into multiple lines with the current version of the xd-shell but what I do is I externalize the whole process by using a shell script to do the whole process.  This is useful if you need to run the same or similar commands several times and your command can be parameterized.  Below is a sample of what your shell script will contain (let's call the file myxdshellfile.sh).  I have similar scripts for all my custom module upload/deploy/definition and streams as well.  If you set it up well, you can parameterize it for deployment into different environments and pass the environment as an input arg.

```
echo -n -e " \
job create --name ${module}_${version} \
--definition \"${moduleDefinition} \
--restartable=false \
--dateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd \
--makeUnique=true \
--partitionResultsTimeout=7200000 \
\
--jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--jdbcUser=${user} \
--jdbcPassword=${pwd} \
--jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://${dbhost} \
\
--version=${version} \
\
\"
" > "$cmdfile"

#write string to file
echo -e -n .${shellpath}/shell/bin/xd-shell --cmdfile ${cmdfile}

#see what's in the file
cat ${cmdfile}

#execute spring-xd shell
bash ${shellpath}/shell/bin/xd-shell --cmdfile ${cmdfile}
```

Comment: Very helpful.. Thank you!